# problem in recording the video and saving that video in sd card in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which involves recording video and saving the video in sd card of android emulator,Can anyone tell how should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator does not support camera. You need a real device to test/debug video recording.

Comment: can u give me an example which i can test

Comment: Use the link that Jana provided.

Comment: Peter i have used the link but thats the think i donot want,,I want to record and play the video,,,,,The code i have used in a test application and it is crashing

Comment: Why dont you just invoke the system camera app in video mode to capture the video?